# Indoor routing using Graphhopper

Tags: java, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I am new to Graphhopper, I am building indoor routing.

Currently everything worked fine in a floor.

I was wondering how to use graphhopper to navigate/routing between floors?

I know that Graphhopper support elevation, can I use it?

Can someone give me advice.

Thanks

Comment: What is so special about routing between floors? As long as there is a connection between the floors it will be exactly the same like regular routing.

Comment: AFAIK no routing engine has support for indoor details, but please consult https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Indoor

Comment: @scai you are right, there is nothing special from a data structure point of view

Comment: @sharon I don't understand which problems you are facing. Did you already tried it? The only problem is the data format, where there is no default importer. But I'm not aware of a standard format for indoor ..

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the only issue might be getting the nearest node from the routing networking for start / end points.

Given a latitude, longitude and **floor**, I don't think Graphhopper can, without a few modifications, limit its query process to a specific floor ([OSM's level tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:level)).

I think it's a different concern from elevation.
Would appreciate Karussell's opinion, that subject interests me too.

Comment: GraphHopper is able to work with any networks. But indeed reading indoor OSM tags is currently not supported. The second issue is regarding the nearest node search as you mentioned as well as the 3rd dimension parameter for the lookup, but nothing in principle which forbids indoor usage :)